# SQL Select ISNULL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

[image]

I used the query below to extract the data fro the table but it does not working.

```
     SELECT A.ID, AVG(ISNULL(score,0)) AS sc FROM A 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
            WHERE A.aClass = '1st'
```

I wanted it to return all the data from Table A with its corresponding average score and return 0 if there is no score yet. Can anyone help me figure out the problem.

Comment: Why do you have a duplicated ID in table b?

Comment: That is for example ID 1 has two records of score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT A.ID, AVG(ISNULL(B.score,0)) AS sc 
 FROM A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
 WHERE A.aClass = '1st'
 GROUP BY A.ID
```